# ST2.2 - Datepicker bug with picker configuration

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i'm using the latest sencha touch release, but found a problem with the datepicker.

This works as expected:

```
var view=new Ext.field.DatePicker({label:"Test"});
```

But if I do it in this way:

```
    var view = new Ext.field.DatePicker({
    label: "Test",
    picker: {
        yearTo: "2020"
    }
});
```

Nothing happens if I click on the datepicker-field. After some time the site even "crashs".

I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m for testing.

Is there maybe a bug within ST 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `new` keyword is not the proper way to create a component in Sencha Touch 2.x

Use `Ext.create`:

```
var view = Ext.create('Ext.field.DatePicker', {
    label: "Test",
    picker: {
        yearTo: 2020 // without the quotes
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I changed my code in the way that you advise, but it doesn't change anything. The datepicker still doesn't open and the browser stucks up. Also please note that my variant works without the picker-configuration, so I don't think that it has something to do with the kind of "object-instantiation".

Comment: It should but I had trouble passing config objects with the new keyword.

Comment: Have you tried yearTo: 2020 (without the ""). Also do you get an error in the console ?

Comment: ... oh thanks, I doesn't thought about it. Yes, without the quotes it works. Seems like that they changed something in the new version. In ST 2.0 it worked with the quotes. To Answer your question: No, there wasn't any error on the console.